# Errors installing Linux Malware Detector on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, malware

Upon running ./install .sh, I get...

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/sbin/maldet’: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/sbin/lmd’: No such file or directory
```

then,

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/maldet missing LSB information
```

I assume the first error results in the second. All installation instructions I've seen do not anticipate this. Question - Is there a work-around, or do I need to find an alternative server malware program that's Ubuntu friendly?

Answer (score 1):

I was reluctant to try the most obvious solution, but it worked. Create directory '/usr/local/sbin', then install. The LSB warning still occurred, but doesn't prevent maldet from running.